# reflection. How to know sibling field value?

Tags: java, reflection, field

I have following class:

```
class CampaignBeanDto {

    Date startDate;

    @MyAnnotation
    Date endDate;

}
```

I need the reference to field `endDate`

I should know which value has value `startDate` for same instance

Comment: I would avoid depending on order of fields (but I may be wrong). Can't you scan all fields and find one with proper annotation?

Comment: how can I get reference to CampaignBeanDto instance if I have only field?

Comment: You create one with `CampaignBeanDto dto = new CampaignBeanDto()` and use `dto` as reference (or you use an existing one).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `if I have only field`?

Comment: *"how can I get reference to CampaignBeanDto instance if I have only field?"* You can't. `Field` is not linked to an instance.

Comment: @Radiodef Oh....you are right. But I need to resolve this problem

Comment: Do I understand your problem correctly: you have some value, like `"foo"`. This value is used in some unknown by you class and you want to get value of sibling of this field in this unknown class? If so then your problem is close to impossible to solve because your value could be used (1) in many classes and reflection can't track which field exactly is using this value (2) in many instances of your class, so which instance do you think should be right?

Comment: @Pshemo unfortunately looks like it is impossible using reflection. Is  there another way?

Comment: yes - a database query?

Comment: Can you put in your value some mapping to object which contains it? Something like `Pair p=Pair(holder, data)` where holder would contain information about instance holding this data, and probably name of field?

Comment: @Mr Spoon trying to realize hibernate validation

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to do? I'm not sure I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wrote `@MyAnnotation` on top of `endDate` I believe what you want is to retrieve a field which is annotated with some annotation.

You can achieve this that way :

```
for(Field f : CampaignBeanDto.class.getFields())
{
    if(f.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class) != null)
    {
         //this is the field you are searching
    }
}
```

If the field is always named `endDate` then you can simply do :

```
for(Field f : CampaignBeanDto.class.getFields())
{
    if(f.getName().equals("endDate"))
    {
         //this is the field you are searching
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get all the fields from the instance provided. It will scan the annotations. will get all the value of the fields having your custom annotation

```
Field[] fields = instance.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
if(instance.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class) != null){
        for (Field field : fields) {
            boolean access = field.isAccessible();
            field.setAccessible(true);

            //getting value
            System.out.println(field.get(instance));

            field.setAccessible(access);

        }
}
```

Comment: i got it from you that part so i clicked your answer useful.. :) you could have edited u know